# Neural network tool in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I wish to design a multi-layer feed-forward neural network classifier on fisheriris dataset in MATLAB.

How to go about it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two most commonly used toolboxes for the neural networks in MATLAB are:

- [Neural Network Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/neural-network/index.html)
- [Netlab](http://www1.aston.ac.uk/eas/research/groups/ncrg/resources/netlab/)

Here is a demo from [Neural Network Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/neural-network/index.html)'s documentation that illustrates using a neural network as a classifier to identify the sex of crabs from physical dimensions of the crab, from which you can take inspiration for the iris data set: http://www.mathworks.com/products/neural-network/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/nnet/classify_crab_demo.html